# How to create a new column based on the filtering and calculation in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset like:

| ymd | revenue |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-07-17 | 2 |
| 2022-07-17 | 3 |
| 2022-07-18 | 4 |
| 2022-07-18 | 5 |

I want to convert into this format:

| ymd | rev_sum |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-07-17 | 5 |
| 2022-07-18 | 9 |

I've tried

```
data["rev_sum"] = sum(
    data[data["ymd"] == "2022-07-17"]["revenue"]
)
data["rev_sum"] = sum(
    data[data["ymd"] == "2022-07-18"]["revenue"]
)
```

But this one updates columns with the last date.

I've also tried :

```
data.loc[data["ymd"] == "2022-07-17"]["rev_sum"] = data.loc[data["ymd"] == "2022-07-17"]["revenue"].sum()
```

This time I got 'Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead' error message.

What should I do? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`pd.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) with `aggfunc='sum'` on `column='revenue'`.

```
df = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['ymd'], values='revenue', 
                    aggfunc='sum').reset_index()

print(df)
```

---

```
          ymd  revenue
0  2022-07-17        5
1  2022-07-18        9
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ymd': {0: '2022-07-17', 
                           1: '2022-07-17', 
                           2: '2022-07-18',  
                           3: '2022-07-18'},
                   'revenue': {0: 2, 1: 3, 2: 4, 3: 5}})

#to sum values by date
sum_rev = df.groupby('ymd').agg({'revenue':'sum'})

print(sum_rev)

            revenue
ymd                
2022-07-17        5
2022-07-18        9

#if you want to create a column in existing df, use:
df['sum_rev'] = df.groupby('ymd')['revenue'].transform(sum)

print(df)
          ymd  revenue  rev_sum
0  2022-07-17        2        5
1  2022-07-17        3        5
2  2022-07-18        4        9
3  2022-07-18        5        9
```

Comment: This is not the exact solution I am looking for but thank you very much!